# Issue with Spring MockMVC and WebMvcTest not returning expected results

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, testing

I'm currently working on a Spring Boot application and facing an issue when writing tests for my controllers. I have a controller class called TableController, and I'm trying to test the `getById` method using Spring's MockMvc. However, I'm not getting the expected results, and I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Here's my setup:

```
@WebMvcTest(TableController.class)
@WithMockUser
public class TableControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @MockBean
    private TableService tableService;
    private String rootUri;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp(){
        this.rootUri = "/tables";
    }
```

In my test method:

```
@Test
    public void getTableById() throws Exception {
        // Arrange
        Integer id = 1;
        Table table = new Table(id);
        String tableUri = rootUri + "/" + id;    // /tables/1
        when(this.tableService.getById(id)).thenReturn(table);

        // Act
        RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(tableUri, id)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        // Assert
        this.mockMvc.perform(request)
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(id)));
    }
```

And this is my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/tables")
public class TableController {
    @Autowired
    TableService tableService;

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Table> getById(@PathVariable Integer id){
        Table table = this.tableService.getById(id);

        if (table != null) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(table); // 200 OK
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build(); // 404 Not Found
        }
    }
```

The issue is that I'm getting a 404 error instead of the expected result. It seems that the TableController isn't returning what I'm mocking in the TableService. I'm not sure if I'm missing something in the configuration or if there's an issue with my test setup.

Any guidance on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(tableUri, id)` Will lead to a URL in the form of `/tables/1/1` which doesn't have any mapping. Either use a pattern or ommit the `id` in te `get` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your test setup. `MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(tableUri, id)` will lead to a URL of `/tables/1/1` for which there is no mapping. To solve either use a URL pattern `/tables/{id}` as the `tableUri` property, or ommit the `id` parameter from the `get` call.

```java
String tableUri = rootUri + "/{id}";
RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(tableUri, id)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

or

```java
RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get(tableUri)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

Both should work.

Comment: Thanks! With this and adding a getter to my entity class the problem was solved!